# Invoke default command line parsing method from any application

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

I am passing in a complex string as an argument to my Console application. I noticed that the resultant `string[] args` array in my Main method is what I want that string to be parsed as.

Now, I want to be able to parse strings of this format and the get the same `string[]` in other parts of my framework, *outside of my console application/process* as well and do not want to reinvent the wheel. I tried to see if I could find and invoke the framework method that is used to parse command line arguments that are passed to the Main method but could not find anything. I read about some command line parsing options including NDesk but cannot use that in my present situation.

Anyone aware of this framework method(s)? Or any other ideas to go about this?

Comment: Why can't you use NDesk.Options (or its cousin, Mono.Options)? We must know that if we are going to suggest some alternative.

Comment: Isn't the array of strings coming into a console application essentially just `var stringArray = someString.Split(new {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`?

Comment: @Scott: Thats not entirely true. It does not split on every space. My string has quotes and there are words within quotes that have space between them. But those words within quotes come in as one string

Comment: Have a look at CLAP (https://github.com/adrianaisemberg/CLAP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Regular Expression:

```
string input = "this is \"a string\" separated by spaces \"with quotes\" also";
Regex r = new Regex("[^\\s\"']+|\"([^\"]*)\"|'([^']*)'");
var matches = r.Matches(input);
```

Figure an explanation would be good:

`[^\\s\"']+` matches 1+ characters up to a space or a double quote

`|` OR

`\"([^\"]*)\"` matches 0+ characters inside of double quotes that is not a double quote itself

`|` OR

`'([^']*)'` matches 0+ characters inside of a single quote that is not a single quote itself

Also, I'm not great with .net Regex, but from what I can tell, they're weird when it comes to matching groups. For me to get the string without the quotes around them, I had to do this weird loop:

```
 var matches = r.Matches(input);
 foreach (Match match in matches)
 {
      Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
 }
```

---

There was an API call you could make if your are running on windows (it *is* supported past vista, regardless of what the pinvoke.net says).  Obviously this is not cross-platform.

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr CommandLineToArgvW(
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpCmdLine,
   out int pNumArgs);
```

Example code [here](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.CommandLineToArgvW)

Comment: Thanks for this. Did you come up with this or did you use reflection to get this. Is there any theory behind coming up with this specific pattern matching?

Comment: Regex was just my go-to answer.  The specific pattern matching it just from what I know about command line arguments on windows.

Comment: @desigeek: do you want to support escapes, like this `"this contains a \"(double quote) character"`?

Comment: @Martin: Yes I want to support escapes. I am not fully aware of all that the default parser does. But what I want is to be consistent between the results of the default parser and whatever method I choose. That's why it is better if I invoke the default method itself.

Comment: @desigeek, in that case, this regex won't work. You might work out some regex to work this out, but it's probably better to just use a parse (either an off-the-shelf one, or your own). **There is no default method for this in the .NET Framework**. This is handled by the environment.

Comment: @Martin: well can we use something like PInvoke or COM functionality to get to it? My knowledge with these is limited so am not very sure it thats possible

Comment: @desigeek: did you see Christopher's edit? He suggested a WinAPI function that does this.

Comment: I am going to accept this an answer, since this is the closest to getting the default behavior I want, though I haven't tried the DllImport yet.